# How to know the width and the height of image using app-engine image API wit python?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

How to know the width and the height of image using app-engine image API wit python, someone adviesed me to use  `the composite function - pass your image in as the sole input image, and specify the canvas size as the desired size of the output image.`

but i didn't understand that!!
any simple example will be very helpful ..
and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your question, you just need to use the attributes width and height from a reference of `google.appengine.api.images.Image`.

An example:

```
flux = img.read() # From your request

image_ref = Image(image_data=flux)
w = image_ref.width
h = image_ref.height
```